# Kendo Grid editable highlighted color

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I had this [kendo demo here](https://dojo.telerik.com/UKIHaweq/2),  want I to achieve, highlighted color only appear once on edited row. Currently the highlighted color appear duplicate when I edit multiple row. How to fixed this? Appreciate your help.

[DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/UKIHaweq/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you already modify it that way, you can reset color by row index, if its `even` set it to gray if its `odd` set it to white and set it to blue if modified:

```
function highlightBlue() {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();

    $.each(data, function (i, row) {
        var item = $('tr[data-uid="' + row.uid + '"]');
        if (item[0].rowIndex % 2 !== 0) {
            item.css("background-color", "#f6f6f6");
        } else {
            item.css("background-color", "white");
        }
        if (row.Modified == "Y") {
            item.css("background-color", "#64B5F6");
        }
    });
}
```

Your modified version: [highlight row](https://dojo.telerik.com/IZOwiyOm)

EDIT:

To make it easier you can add class on cell select and remove class on cell close.

```
<style>
    .highlight {
      background-color: red !Important;
    }
</style>
.....
edit: function(e){
    $(e.container[0]).closest("tr").addClass("highlight");
},
cellClose: function(e) {
    $(e.container[0]).closest("tr").removeClass("highlight");
}
```

With this way we preserve the background colors, here is updated code:
[On cell open and close](https://dojo.telerik.com/iMOxanUX)

Comment: is there any option without using background color? this is because i'm using different theme color.